# How to get a time between two dates or time field?

Tags: validation-rule

I need to know how could I get a time between two dates or time or datetime field ??

Actually I want to know that any field are between 11:00AM and 11:29AM timings or not???

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you doing this in Apex? or VisualForce? or a formula?

Comment: @Dominic in an Apex Trigger

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using a formula field, you can set up a Boolean formula that evaluates this condition

```
SomeDateTimeField__c < CampaignEndDateTime__c && SomeDateTimeField__c  > CampaignStartDateTime__c
```

If you are doing this in Apex then it is simple as well. Below I am just giving some datetime values. You could use your actual object and fields.

```
MyObject__c myObject = [select id, SomeDateTimeField__c ,CampaignEndDateTime__c, CampaignStartDateTime__c from myObject__c where id =: someId ]

DateTime dt = myObject.SomeDateTimeField__c;
DateTime dtStart = myObject.CampaignStartDateTime__c;
DateTime dtEnd = myObject.CampaignEndDateTime__c;

if(dt>dtStart && dt<dtEnd)
    System.debug('## In the zone');
else System.debug('## Missed it');
```

Comment: I have two seperate time and I want to know either a field's time is in between the two time or not. For example: 
Field Name: Meeting Time
MeetingTimeStart: 11AM
MeetingTimeEnds: 1130AM

So, i need to ask how to get the to know either this field is in between the proposes timings or not.

Comment: Well so either the Formula or the Apex should work for you. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: This is what I wanted: Datetime.now().format('hh:mm:ss a');    and this if(time1<startTime && time1>finishTime

Answer (score 0):

First I wanted to do like this to fulfill my requirement but this is i think not possible so I came up with this solution
This is what I wanted: Datetime.now().format('hh:mm:ss a'); and this if(time1finishTime